# How to upgrade HAProxy on OpsWorks

Tags: haproxy, aws-opsworks

We are using an AWS OpsWorks stack with Chef Version 11.10. with the [default HAProxy Layer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/layers-haproxy.html). We would like to upgrade the HAProxy to the latest version 1.6-stable (from the default 1.4-stable).
There seems to be a [dedicated PPA](http://haproxy.debian.net/#?distribution=Ubuntu&release=trusty&version=1.6) for our Ubuntu version.

But where can we make OpsWorks use this PPA to install HAProxy?

In the [default cookbook](https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/tree/release-chef-11.10/haproxy) there is a [default attributes file](https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/blob/release-chef-11.10/haproxy/attributes/default.rb) that has the following lines:

```
default[:haproxy][:version] = '1.4.22'
default[:haproxy][:patchlevel] = '1'
default[:haproxy][:rpm] = "haproxy-#{node[:haproxy][:version]}-#{node[:haproxy][:patchlevel]}.#{rhel_arch}.rpm"
default[:haproxy][:rpm_url] = "#{node[:opsworks_commons][:assets_url]}/packages/#{node[:platform]}/#{node[:platform_version]}/#{node[:haproxy][:rpm]}"
```

Overwriting the file in our cookbooks and naïvely changing the version number here does not have the desired effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up overwriting the recipe `haproxy/recipes/default.rb` like so:

```
#Install software-properties-common if not installed
package 'software-properties-common' do
  action :install
end

#Add PPA for haproxy 1.6 and update repo
execute "add-ppa-update" do
  command "add-apt-repository ppa:vbernat/haproxy-1.6 && apt-get update -y"
  action :run
end

package "haproxy" do
  retries 3
  retry_delay 5

  version '1.6.4-3ppa1~trusty'
  action  :install
end

if platform?('debian','ubuntu')
  template '/etc/default/haproxy' do
    source 'haproxy-default.erb'
    owner 'root'
    group 'root'
    mode 0644
  end
end

include_recipe 'haproxy::service'

template '/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg' do
  source 'haproxy.cfg.erb'
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode 0644
  notifies :restart, "service[haproxy]"
end

template "/etc/haproxy/server.pem" do
  source    "server.pem.erb"
  owner     'root'
  group     'root'
  mode      0600
  notifies  :restart, "service[haproxy]"
end

service 'haproxy' do
  action [:enable, :start]
end
```

Additionally we needed to update the haproxy.conf to work with the new version.

Everything runs beautifully now.